# Kamon with Datadog throwing java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError major/minor 51.0

Tags: java, akka, monitoring, statsd

I'm trying to send data to datadog using kamon. My setup is the following:

```
io.kamon
kamon-core_2.10
0.3.1


io.kamon
kamon-datadog_2.10
0.3.1

<SCALA_MAJOR>2.10</SCALA_MAJOR>
<SCALA_VERSION>2.10.3</SCALA_VERSION>
<AKKA_VERSION>2.3.2</AKKA_VERSION>

JDK 1.6

Datadog Agent Version: 4.4.0
```

I'm getting the following exception at akka startup:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:                    kamon/util/GlobPathFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLlassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kamon was being built for Java 1.7 by default. Now, it will support 1.6

Comment: Our support folks are happy to help if needed: mention @support in the event stream.